# Разъясните пожалуйста момент с типом данных List<> с#

Tags: c#

На сколько я понимаю, это указательный тип данных, т.е. передается в функции не объект,а ссылка?
Тогда если я создам где-то объект List. А после буду удалять/добавлять в него строки в нескольких потоках - мне кажется возникнет исключение т.к. я пытаюсь изменить один и тот же объект из разных потоков одновременно. Или это работает как-то иначе?

Comment: Есть [ConcurrentBag<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) для списка в потоках ....... а есть еще [SynchronizedCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx) .........в общем и целом для работы в потоках используются потокобезопасные коллекции https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/index

Comment: Так точно. `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>` это и есть потокобезопасная замена для  `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` .......... Также, как я написал выше, для работы в потоках для коллекций представлен целый список

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  С чего она замена? List держит порядок, а ConcurrentBag нет

Comment: @vitidev есть предложения лучше?

Comment: Спасибо. Изучу. Эти объекты могут продублироваться при передаче в функцию в другом потоке? Всм, не получится ли так, что я изменяю объект, а изменяется его некая локальная копия?

Comment: @vitidev Нюансы есть всегда, для этого изучается документация

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это разные по логике работы коллекции. Поэтому не следует говорить, что одно заменяет другое в мультипоточном окружении.

Comment: эййй) Ну хорош. Меня по сути интересовало другое. 
Может ли объект List<T> продублироваться, без написанного мною 
"List<T> two = ListTOne"?

Comment: @АлександрЛи что значит `продублироваться, без написанного мною "List<T> two = ListTOne"`?

Comment: "Всм, не получится ли так, что я изменяю объект, а изменяется его некая локальная копия?"

Comment: @vitidev читай выше: "Нюансы есть всегда, для этого изучается документация". Если есть предложения - пиши ответ, не стесняйся

Comment: или можете использовать ReaderWriterLock

Comment: @vitidev сутки прошли, а ответа от вас нет. похоже только чесать языком умеете. и неправильно интерпретировать прочитанное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ваш коммент с петросянской картинкой, как и мой, что я прекращаю диалог, потерли. Так что просто успокойтесь. А если вам прям так нужен ответ, то ConcurrentBag не заменяет список, потому что это не "нюансы", а разные вещи по принципу работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List<> действительно ссылочный тип данных. Память для него выделяется на куче (heap) и всюду передается ссылка на адрес в куче.
Поэтому,  продублироваться, как Вы пишете в комментариях, List сам по себе не может. Но при работе с ним из нескольких потоков, действительно может быть unexpected result. Это уж как Вы доступ к коллекции организуете и что с ним делать будете. Можете и исключение вызвать, если, например, обратиться по индексу к элементу, который уже удален другим потоком. 
Если Вам нужна потокобезопасная коллекция, то Вам уже посоветовали Concurrent коллекции. Альтернатива -  организовать потокобезопасность руками, например через lock(object).